# How do i set value for all objects in background? [parse.com]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Heres my code so far:

```
   var query2 = PFQuery(className: "Post")
             query2.whereKey("alias", equalTo: self.currentname)

             query2.setValue(self.usernametextfield.text, forKey: "alias")

             query2.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, NSError) -> Void in

                                    for objects in objects {



                                        }


                                    }

                            }
```

I want to set objects["alias"] equal to a string for all the objects retrieved from the query. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want all the objects retrieved to get the same value for the key "alias"? Eg. objects[0]["alias"] = myString, objects[1]["alias"] = myString etc?

Comment: yes all the objects retrieved to have same value for key "alias"

Comment: Couldn't you, in the for loop, do `object.setObject(yourObject, forKey: "alias")`, and then `object.saveEventually()`?

Comment: where would i add in the value  (string)

Comment: yourObject is the thing your setting the alias column to be, so if you have your string in a variable you could put it there.

Comment: okay that worked. i was trying that but for some reason autofill wasnt working so i thought it was the wrong code. THANKS! i feel like an idiot

Comment: Good luck, glad it worked out :)